# expected length of linked list

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a datatype whose objects will be sequences of elements that has the following two methods

prepend($x, T$) which will insert an element to x to the beginning of the sequence T

search($T, i$) which returns the ith element in the given sequence

T is a linked list. prepend takes $1$ step. Search takes $i$ steps

Suppose T has exactly one element and a sequence of n operations are performed. You are given that prepend has probability $p$ and search has probability $1-p$ for each operation. The value of $i$ is chosen uniformly from $[1, \dots, T]$

Q) Derive the expected length for the linked list just before the k'th operation is performed

---

so we need the weighted average of all possible values of some random variable. for each $X_i$ let it be the number of steps for given events. If theres a prepend we add a node whereas if theres an access we do nothing to the length. How do we come up with an equation for expectd length?

$E(X) = something \cdot (k-1)$ since just before $k$ but not sure how to derive the probability yet

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's fine I understood it after your response

Comment: Thanks! I believe I have shown the formula clearly and rigorously in my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $E(X) = something \cdot (k-1)$

That $something$ is $p$. The full formula should be $E(Y)=1+p(k-1)$, where $Y$ is the random variable that is the length for the linked list just before the $k$-th operation is performed.

To convince yourself that $p$ is the right answer, try a few cases. When $p=1$, every operation adds one element to $T$. When $p=0$, no prepend operation will happen. When $p=1/2$, an element is added about half of the times. Make sense?

Here is the simple reason why. Let $Y_i$ be the increase of length in step $i$. Then

- $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ are independent random variables,
- $E(Y_i)=p$ for all $i$ since the probability of prepending is $p$ for each operation.

Since the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations for independent variables, we have
$$\begin{align}
E(Y)
&=E(1+ Y_1+ Y_2+ \cdots+ Y_{k-1})\\
&=1+ E(Y_1)+E(Y_2)+\cdots+E(Y_{k-1})\\
&=1+ p(k-1)
\end{align}$$
where 1 comes from the initial one element in $T$.

Comment: The list starts with one element.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus you beat OP and me. Updating ...

Comment: should it be $E(X) = 1 + p(k-1)$ since it starts with 1 element?

Answer (score 1):

You can break this down into basics. Recall that the expected value of the length will be the sum of all possible lengths multiplied by their probability:
$$\mathbb{E}[L] = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} i \cdot P(L = i)$$

The probability $P(L = i)$ is the probability of length being equal to $i$ after $k-1$ operations. This means exactly $i$ of the $k-1$ operations would've been `prepend` and $k - 1 - i$ operations would've been `search`. The probability of this will be:

$$P(L = i) = p^{i} \cdot (1 - p)^{k - 1 - i} \cdot N(i, k - 1)$$

Where $N(i, k - 1)$ is the number of ways we can do $i$ `prepends` out of the `k-1` total operations. Consider that there are multiple orders to those operations (e.g. {`prepend`, `prepend`, `search`} and {`prepend`, `search`, `prepend`} both reach length 2). We can "choose" $i$ of the $k - 1$ operations to be `prepend` then the rest will be `search`, thus we have:

$$N(i, k - 1) = \binom{k - 1}{i}$$

Now we can plug this back in:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[L] & = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} i \cdot p^{i} \cdot (1 - p)^{k - 1 - i} \cdot \binom{k - 1}{i}
\end{align*}$$

You can see this is clearly the expected value of a binomial distribution and we get:

$$\mathbb{E}[L] = p \cdot (k-1)$$

(See [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/in-in-grade-12-ncert/in-in-probability-of-events/copy-of-binomial-random-variables/v/expected-value-of-binomial-distribution) if you want to work through these last two steps precisely).

Comment: I am afraid that you have been trying to make something very simple more difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was going back to the basics of expected value over a binomial distribution and showing how you get there.

Comment: I agree that you are going to the basics. It might be enlightening as well to show that complicated meticulous formula will lead to the same formula. On the other hand, your computation also uses the fact P(AB)=P(A)P(B) if A and B are independent. From that fact/definition, it is immediate that sum of the expectation is the expectation of the sum.

Comment: Fair enough, this is just how I initially broke it down. Sums of expectations did not initially come to me.

Comment: Upvoted, partly to emphasize the determination. Often, one can get an answer by going back to the very basics and taking pains to advance a lot of reasoning.