# Deriving the expected number of steps that is taken to perform the k'th operation

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a datatype whose objects will be sequences of elements that has the following two methods

prepend($x, T$) which will insert an element to x to the beginning of the sequence T

search($T, i$) which returns the ith element in the given sequence

T is a linked list. prepend takes $1$ step. Search takes $i$ steps

Suppose T has exactly one element and a sequence of n operations are performed. You are given that prepend has probability $p$ and search has probability $1-p$ for each operation. The value of $i$ is chosen uniformly from $[1, \dots, T]$

Q) Deriving the expected number of steps that is taken to perform the k'th operation

---

This would be the average of all possible events so number of search and prepends to the expected length. Expected length is given to be p (k-1). Derived from below

[expected length of linked list](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106459/expected-length-of-linked-list)

search takes i steps (probability 1-p). Prepend takes 1 step (probability is p ).

$E(X) = search(1) + search(2) + \cdots + search((p(k-1)))$

Not sure how to get an exact value for it

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_i$ be the random variable denoting the length of $T$ prior to the $i$th operation. You should be able to calculate $\mathbb{E}[N_i]$.

The expected running time $T_i$ of the $i$th operation is
$$
p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot \frac{1+\cdots+N_i}{N_i} = p + (1-p) \frac{N_i+1}{2}.
$$
Given $\mathbb{E}[N_i]$, you should be able to calculate $\mathbb{E}[T_i]$ using this formula.

I leave you to figure out all remaining details.

Comment: "The expected running time Ti of the ith operation is" what does this mean? Expected running time, is that expected number of steps ?

Comment: In your case, expected number of steps.

Comment: So I'm confused wouldn't the above formula be $E(T_i)$ what the question is looking for ?

Comment: The formula involves the random variable $N_i$.

Comment: Not sure how to do it that way but I tried something similar $E(X) = p \cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{1+p(k-1)}}{1+p(k-1)} + (1-p) \cdot 1$


$ = p \frac{1+2 \cdots + (1+p(k-1))}{(1+p(k-1))} + 1 - p$


$ = p \frac{p(k-1)}{2} + 1 - p$. Since $N_i = 1 + p(k-1)$

Comment: You’ll have to take it from here on your own.

Comment: Note that $N_i$ is a random variable. It is *not* equal to $1+p(k-1)$, though its expectation is.