# Derive the expected # of steps that are taken to perform all the operations (n operations)

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a datatype whose objects will be sequences of elements that has the following two methods

prepend($x, T$) which will insert an element to x to the beginning of the sequence T

search($T, i$) which returns the ith element in the given sequence

T is a linked list. prepend takes $1$ step. Search takes $i$ steps

Suppose T has exactly one element and a sequence of n operations are performed. You are given that prepend has probability $p$ and search has probability $1-p$ for each operation. The value of $i$ is chosen uniformly from $[1, \dots, T]$

Q) Derive the expected # of steps that are taken to perform all the operations (n operations).

for prepend it takes 1 step and n times would be $n \cdot p$

for search it takes $(1) + (2)  + \cdots + n(1-p)$ where each number means the size [1,...,T].

I think prepend is right but I'm not completely sure about search. If theres 1 element in the sequence it would be n times if it were 2 it could be either 1 or 2 and that takes i (i is somewhere between [1...T]) times and so on for 3 until we are at n(1-p).

hence

$E(X) = n \cdot p + \left((1) + (2)  + \cdots + n(1-p) \right)$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Related: [expected length of linked list after $n$ operations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106459/expected-length-of-linked-list).

Comment: Use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: k'th operation =/= all nth operation. Not the same albeit close.

Comment: @mammywood Suppose they are indeed "not the same". I am going to raise another question asking for "the expected # of steps that are taken to perform the first $m$ operations", which is a new question similar to your versions but not the same since $m\not=k$ and $m\not=n$. I am going to raise still another question asking for "the expected # of steps that are taken to perform the first $j$ operations", which is a new question since $j\not=k$ and $j\not=m$ and $j\not=n$. I am going to raise ...; you get the idea. All $n$ operations are none other than the first $n$ operations.

Comment: Or did you actually mean the $k$-th operation **alone** in the other question? If that is true, can you emphasize that single-ness in the other question and  make sure that you get the right answer for the other question first?

Comment: Other question was asking for the expected step for a k operation. Example what is the expected time of the sixth operation ($k = 6$). Whereas in this one I am asking for all n operation so if n = 6, all the operation leading up to 6. Further thinking I think the answer to this would be $E(length) = \sum_{k=1}^{length} E(K_i)$ where $K_i$ is the one from the previous question?

Comment: While the questions are formally different, they are very closely related. There’s no need to ask us for each and every step of this exercise. Do some of it on your own. You will never understand the concepts unless you grapple with them on your own.